# What is the thesis behind Leonard Schwartz' Heavy Hands

Tags: cardio, walking

I love to walk and am looking at upping my game.

I stumbled upon Heavyhands Walking by Leonard Schwartz [see here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0878576924)

Before I buy the book I thought I should ask folks here of their expert opinion on what his regimen is all about?

It also looks a bit dated and wanted to see if his work have been superseded by other theories and practice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If it's about farmer walks, or ‘walking the load’, then the author is on point.
Farmer walks can be adjusted in different ways to train pretty much the entire body and different systems of the body: cardiovascular, nervous, or muscular system.

- up stairs to prioritize the legs
- one-sided only to build strong obliques and back muscles
- odd handles to build crushing or pinching power
- running to build power
- super-heavy to build shoulder and arm muscles
- light-weight for long walks to burn calories and maintain muscle while getting older

And these are a few examples, the farmer carry can be used in many more ways for more specific purposes, it is safe to assume that yes one can build fitness from just walking with weights.
Literally walking your way to a healthier life or and stronger body.

Answer (score 0):

The heart works much harder when the weights are pumped at higher levels,  with a weight that you can vary the movements. Examples are see saw presses, alternating high strides, backing down with hammer curls, etc. If you are a beginner, even 2 pound weights will be difficult to manage a very brisk pace. This is the essence of the exercise. Your breathing and heart rate will be greatly elevated, and if you do this for 15 to 30 minutes, you will feel it. As you find it easier, gradually add higher weights. After a few weeks, check your progress as far as resting heart rate and overall endurance. I bet your shoulders will feel fantastic, due to all the different planes of motion. Great for deskbound people.